# adding select options to select acording to another select

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, forms, formik

I have a formik form that has three field select one for for country and one for city one for country number code i have the the info in a data.js

```js
export const countries = {
    en: [
        { value: 'jo', label: 'Jordan',
        { value: 'ae', label: 'United Arab Emirates},
        { value: 'sa', label: 'Saudi Arabia'},
        { value: 'iq', label: 'Iraq', },
        { value: 'kw', label: 'Kuwait'},
        { value: 'qa', label: 'Qatar'},
        { value: 'lb', label: 'Lebanon'}
    ],
    ar: [
        { value: 'jo', label: 'الاردن' },
        { value: 'ae', label: 'الامرات العربيه المتحدة' },
        { value: 'sa', label: 'السعوديه' },
        { value: 'iq', label: 'العراق' },
        { value: 'kw', label: 'الكويت' },
        { value: 'qa', label: 'قطر' },
        { value: 'lb', label: 'لبنان' }
    ] }
export const cities = {
    en: {
        ae: [
            { value: 'dubai', label: 'Dubai' },
            { value: 'abudhabi', label: 'Abu Dhabi' }
        ],
        jo: [{ value: 'amman', label: 'Amman' }],
        qa: [{ value: 'doha', label: 'Doha' }],
        kw: [{ value: 'kuwait', label: 'Kuwait' }],
        sa: [
            { value: 'riyadh', label: 'Riyadh' },
            { value: 'jeddah', label: 'Jeddah' },
            { value: 'khobar', label: 'Khobar' },
            { value: 'dhahran', label: 'Dhahran' },
            { value: 'dammam', label: 'Dammam' },
        ],
        lb: [{ value: 'beirut', label: 'Beirut' }],
        iq: [{ value: 'baghdad', label: 'Baghdad' }]
    },
    ar: {
        ae: [
            { value: 'dubai', label: 'دبي' },
            { value: 'abudhabi', label: 'ابو ظبي' }
        ],
        jo: [{ value: 'amman', label: 'عمان' }],
        qa: [{ value: 'doha', label: 'الدوحه' }],
        kw: [{ value: 'kuwait', label: 'الكويت' }],
        sa: [
            { value: 'riyadh', label: 'الرياض' },
            { value: 'jeddah', label: 'جدة' },
            { value: 'khobar', label: 'الخبر' },
            { value: 'dhahran', label: 'الظهران' },
            { value: 'dammam', label: 'الدمام' },
        ],
        lb: [{ value: 'beirut', label: 'بيروت' }],
        iq: [{ value: 'baghdad', label: 'بغداد' }]
    } }
export const countryCodes = [
    { value: '+962', label: '+962', code: 'jo' },
    { value: '+966', label: '+966', code: 'sa' },
    { value: '+965', label: '+965', code: 'kw' },
    { value: '+964', label: '+964', code: 'iq' },
    { value: '+961', label: '+961', code: 'lb' },
    { value: '+974', label: '+974', code: 'qa' },
    { value: '+971', label: '+971', code: 'ae' }
]
```

I'm mapping over the counters and put every one label in an option tag, when select a country should only return the cites of that country and auto select the first value for the cites and select the correct phone code
here's my form

```js
     <Formik
                        initialValues={initialValues}
                        validationSchema={props.params !== 'ar' ? FormSchmaEn : FormSchmaAr}
                        onSubmit={() => {
                            handleSubmit()
                            setRenderPreferredContactMethod(() => true)
                        }}
                    >
                        {formikProps => {
                            const { values, setFieldValue } = formikProps;
                            return (
                                <div className='container' style={{ marginTop: '150px' }}>
                                   
                                    <Form className="container">
                                        
                                        <hr style={{ maxWidth: '480px', width: '100%' }} />
                                        <div className="row justify-content-center">
                                            <div className="col form-input" style={{ marginBottom: '10px', width: '100%', maxWidth: "500px" }}>
                                                <Field as="select" name='country' value={values.country} onChange={e => (setFieldValue('country', e.target.value))}
                                                    className="form-control" style={props.params !== 'ar' ? { textAlignLast: 'left' } : { textAlignLast: 'right' }}>
                                                    {props.params !== 'ar' ? <option value="Country">Country</option> : <option value="Country" hidden>البلد</option>}
                                                    {countries[`${props.params}`].map((country, index) => (
                                                        <option key={index} value={countries.en[index].label} onChange={e => setFieldValue('city', countries.en[index].cities)}>{country.label}</option>
                                                    ))}
                                                    
                                                </Field>
                                                <ErrorMessage name="country" component="div" style={{ color: 'red' }} />
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div className="row justify-content-center">
                                            <div className="col form-input" style={{ marginBottom: '10px', width: '100%', maxWidth: "500px" }}>
                                                <Field value="test" as="select" type="text" name='city' className="form-control" style={props.params !== 'ar' ? { textAlignLast: 'left' } : { textAlignLast: 'right' }}>
                                                    {props.params !== 'ar' ? <option hidden></option> : <option value="المدينه" hidden>{country.cities}</option>}
                                                    {countries[`${props.params}`].map((city, index) => (

                                                        <option key={index} >{city.cities.label}</option>

                                                    ))}
                                                </Field>
                                                <ErrorMessage name="city" component="div" style={{ color: 'red' }} />
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div className={props.params !== 'ar' ? "row justify-content-center" : "row justify-content-center flex-row-reverse"}>
                                            <div className="col-4 form-input" style={{ marginBottom: '10px', width: '100%', maxWidth: "150px" }}>
                                                <Field as="select" type="text" name='numberCode' className="form-control" onClick={(e) => setNumberCode(() => e.target.value)}>
                                                    <option value="+1" hidden>+1</option>
                                                    {countryCodes.map((countryCode, index) => (
                                                        <option key={index}>
                                                            {countryCodes[index].label}
                                                        </option>
                                                    ))}
                                                </Field>
                                            </div>
                                            <div className="col-8 form-input" style={{ marginBottom: '10px', width: '100%', maxWidth: "350px" }}>
                                                <Field type="text" name="phoneNumber" className={props.params !== 'ar' ? "form-control" : "form-control ar"} placeholder="111 111" onKeyUp={(e) => setPhoneNumber(() => numberCode + e.target.value)} />
                                                <ErrorMessage name="phoneNumber" component="div" style={{ color: 'red' }} />
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                      
                                    </Form>
                                </div>
                            )
                        }}
                    </Formik>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: What's the exact question here? Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask :)

Answer (score 1):

Upon selecting the country, you need to store your selection in some sort of state (useState). Then based on that, you can easily then conditionally render what you want (the cities based on stored value).

Some pseudo code:

on select - set country => `jo`.

if `country` => render city selector.

if `en` => output english cities list.

Edit: I'd also suggest using a more up to date react.